# TypeScript TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any'

Tags: typescript

I study Typescript. I get this error:

> Error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'User'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'User'.

Code:

```
interface User {
        genderInterestMe: string;
        viewMeGender: string;
        radiusViewUsers: number;
        notifyStatus: boolean;
    }
```

```
const handleChangeFormData = (event: Event, newValue: number | boolean | string) => {
            const {target} = event
            const name: string = (target as HTMLButtonElement).name
            let obj:User= {
                genderInterestMe: genderInterestMe,
                viewMeGender: viewMeGender,
                radiusViewUsers: radiusViewUsers,
                notifyStatus: notifyStatus
            }
            obj[name] = newValue
            menuSettings(obj)
    };
```

Error occurs at

```
obj[name] = newValue
```

I tried using

```
obj[name as keyof User] = newValue
```

and `newValue: never` - it's not working. Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 0):

Should have been added to the interface

```
[key: string]: string | number | boolean;
```